# IES lights in Blender 2.82

Tags: node-editor, light, lighting

Since Blender 2.8 there is the built-in feature to use IES-files for realistic lighting. In 2.80 you could just select a point light source, click on "Use Nodes" and add an IES-texture node in the Shading tab.
In 2.82 I can't find the "Use Nodes" option anymore and when selecting a light source and going in the Shading tab, there are no nodes yet.

Does anyone know where to activate the "Use Nodes" option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the Cycles render engine.
It's not there when using Eevee :).

[image]

Comment: You're absolutely right! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tongamann Happy to help :). No idea why Eevee doesn't support this.